# Integral inequality: $|f(b)| - |f(a)| \le \int^1_0 |f'(x)|dx$

Tags: integration

Given $f$ is continuous in $[0, 1]$ and differentiable in $(0, 1)$, I need to show that $$|f(a)| - |f(b)| \le \int^1_0|f'(x)|dx$$
for all $a, b \in (0, 1)$. I have no clue with where to start with this, a hint would be greatly appreciated. I think there's FTC involved, but I don't know how to deal with the modulus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : $|f(b)| - |f(a)| \leq |f(b)-f(a)|$ by the reverse triangle inequality. Then use the fundamental theorem of calculus and $|\int g| \leq \int |g|$ for any $g$.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that if $g$ is nonnegative integrable function and $[a,b]\subset[c,d]$, then $\displaystyle\int_a^bg(x)dx\leqq\int_c^d g(x)dx$.

---

As you say in the comment to first answer, do we use MVT for this problem ?

If we use MVT, we get $c\in (a,b)$ s.t. $$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.$$

Then,
\begin{align}
|f(b)|-|f(a)|
\leqq |f(b)-f(a)|
=(b-a)|f'(c)|
=\int_a^b |f'(c)|dx
\leqq\int_0^1|f'(c)|dx.
\end{align}
Thus, in order to deduce $\displaystyle|f(b)|-|f(a)|\leqq\int_0^1|f'(x)|dx,$ we have to show $\displaystyle\int_0^1|f'(c)|dx\leqq
\int_0^1|f'(x)|dx.$

However, this seems impossible because there is no control for $f'(c).$

---

Then, it is reasonable to prove the claim without MVT.

The way is as @Suspicious_Fred says. More detailly, the proof can be conducted in this procedure.

(i) Triangle inequality : $|f(b)|-|f(a)|\leqq|f(b)-f(a)|.$

(ii) Fundamental theorem of calculus : $f(b)-f(a)=\int_a^bf'(x)dx.$

(iii) Triangle inequality for integral : $|\int_a^b g(x)dx|\leqq\int_a^b|g(x)|dx$ if $g$ is an integrable function and $a,b\in\mathbb R$ satisfy $a<b.$

(iv) $\int_a^bg(x)dx\leqq\int_c^dg(x)dx$ for nonnegative integrable function $g$ and $[a,b]\subset[c,d].$

Can you come to conclusion ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track - the key to this problem is to use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and the Mean Value Theorem. Here is my hint

1. Use the Mean Value Theorem to show that for any $a, b \in (0,1)$, there exists a $c \in (0,1)$ such that $|f(a)|-|f(b)| = f'(c)(a-b)$.
2. Since $|f'(x)|$ is non-negative, we can split the integral into two cases:

   - If $f'(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, then $\int_0^1 |f'(x)| dx = \int_0^1 f'(x) dx = f(1)-f(0)$ (by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus).
   - If $f'(x) < 0$ for some $x \in [0,1]$, then $\int_0^1 |f'(x)| dx = -\int_0^1 f'(x) dx = f(0)-f(1)$.
3. Combining these results, we obtain:

   $|f(a)|-|f(b)| \le |f'(c)|(a-b) \le \int_0^1 |f'(x)| dx$

   where the last inequality follows from the fact that $|f'(c)|$ is bounded above by $\int_0^1 |f'(x)| dx$.